# Detecting corners using Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying  to find the corners of the 4 pillars which are of yellow in colour and also detecting extreme corners of the board which is of white in colour.

Basically i want to calculate the area of whole space after subtracting the area of each pillar.
For that first am trying to identifying the corner of pillars to find the area of each pillar.

[image: Input image]

Here is the code which I tried, I am almost half way through it.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Corner_0.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)

cv2.imwrite('Detected_Corner_0.jpg',img)
```

[image: Output image I got]

I would like to detect corner and calculating the area of the pillar.

When I use Grabcut I am able to apply for one pillar, does this make sense?

[image: After Applying Grabcut]

Comment: "I am almost half way through it": I like your optimism.

Comment: Do you mean the area as seen in the image, or in the real, 3D world ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust area seen in the image

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Thank you. I am trying hard to resolve but somewhere am lagging on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corner detectors often cannot be relied on. The show extra corners and miss the ones you expect. What's more, you have to identify an regroup them.

You obtain interesting results by computing a saturation image (S in LSH). Then by binarization and blob analysis, you can easily find the areas.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Will i be  able to calculate the are if i use the above method as you said

Comment: I never came across the method which u have mentioned, i appreciate if possible can u provide me the code to attain the result. Thanks in advance

Comment: @venkat I have used proprietary software, but you can find that in OpenCV.

Comment: @venkat Try Grabcut and let us know.

Comment: Please have a look at the image after applying Grabcut algorithm @ Yves Daoust

Comment: @venkat: well, you need to find the other faces,don't you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157214/discussion-between-venkat-and-yves-daoust).